# Algorithm for all combinations of an array of doubles with sum equal to 2 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, combinatorics

I am trying to implement an algorithm that for a fixed given array of doubles (i.e. [1.0, 0.5, 0.25] is giving all possible combinations that sum up to for example 1.0. In this case, the output should look like:

```
1.0
0.5 0.5
0.5 0.25 0.25
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
0.25 0.25 0.5
0.25 0.5 0.25
```

I tried to achieve this with two nested for-loops and can't figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my attempt so far:

```
private double[] a = {1, 0.5, 0.25};
private double max = 1;
private String as;
private double help;
private boolean done;

public void comb()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            as ="";
            help = 0;
            while (help < max)
            {
                if(help + a[i] <= max)
                {
                    as += a[i] + " ";
                    help += a[i];
                }
                /*else if (help + a[j] <= max)
                {
                    ausdruck += a[j] + " ";
                    help += a[j];
                }*/
            }
            System.out.println(as);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you post what you've tried so far

Comment: I added my terrible code.

Comment: You may need to add some constraints to make it reasonable to solve. For example, are negative numbers allowed? If not, you can optimize out sums greater than your target. If so, there's not much you can do beyond summing every possible combination of numbers together and see what you get. Other constraints could be the possible lengths of the list, whether numbers in the list can be larger than the target, etc.

Comment: Negative numbers are not in the given array, so they won't occur and numbers in the array aren't larger than the target. The length of the list is fixed.

Comment: Ah, I misread. I thought the list you gave was an example, not the one true list.

Comment: The array I gave was an example, but the one true array will feature the same attributes.

Comment: Do you just need the combinations to do something else with them or is your task to implement the algorithm to build such combinations?

Comment: I need the combinations to do something else with them. And the subset sum algorithm does not yield the results I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using recursion. Below is my approach with some explanation:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = {1, 0.5, 0.25};
        double max = 1;
        //pass the array, target value and an empty list to the method
        comb(a, max, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public static void comb(double[] a, double max, List<Double> scores) {
        //sum the numbers included in the list
        double scoresSum = scores.stream().reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
        //print the list if the sum of numbers in the list equals target value
        if (scoresSum == max) {
            System.out.println(scores);
        } else if (scoresSum > max) {
        //stop the method if the sum of numbers in the list is larger than the target value
        } else {
        //if the sum of numbers in the list is smaller than the target value, for each value from the array:
        //- create copy of the list
        //- add the value
        //- run the method passing the updated list as an argument
            for (double v : a) {
                List<Double> scoresPlusOne = new ArrayList<>(scores);
                scoresPlusOne.add(v);
                comb(a, max, scoresPlusOne);
            }
        }
    }
}
```